# Grub2 is not using kernel grubby provides me. grub.cfg problem?

Tags: boot, grub, uefi

I am using the [linux surface kernel](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface) on Fedora 39, which I want to use as the default kernel GRUB2 selects on startup.

- It got set up as default kernel before and it worked, but then I changed GRUB config with `GRUB_TIMEOUT=3` in `/etc/default/grub` and used the following command to let GRUB show up without a splash screen:

  ```shell
  grub2-editenv - unset menu_auto_hide
  ```
- Then I made the config:

  ```shell
  grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
  ```
- This already worked as expected but I ran the following command as I read you should do this when running on EFI:

  ```shell
  grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
  ```
- Now my linux-surface kernel did not get picked up as default anymore. linux-surface provides a tool to set the default kernel, which I used again:

  ```shellsession
  # linux-surface-default-watchdog.sh
  /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.2-1.surface.fc39.x86_64
  The default is /boot/loader/entries/7c03857f939a498ab1b53ed4b8723e04-6.7.2-1.surface.fc39.x86_64.conf with index 2 and kernel /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.2-1.surface.fc39.x86_64
  ```
- Checking if it is set with grubby provides the following output:

  ```shellsession
  # grubby --default-kernel          
  /boot/vmlinuz-6.7.2-1.surface.fc39.x86_64
  ```

  But this kernel does still not get picked up as default kernel and GRUB2 just picks the first line on boot.

My idea was to just delete `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` as this seems to have been the problem as it worked before, but I am scared that this will somehow destroy GRUB in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my problem with a [fedora docs article](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/).

The problem is that I used `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`. To quote the above linked article:

> Under EFI, GRUB2 looks for its configuration in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`, however the postinstall script of `grub2-common` installs a small shim which chains to the standard configuration at `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Here are the steps I took to get back to the default configuration:

```
# rm -f /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
# dnf reinstall grub2-common
```

This fixed my problem. If you want to change your grub2 configuration on an EFI (fedora) system, you should therefore use `grub2-mkconfig -o  /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and **not** `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`.